# Placing thumbnails inside of tabs

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using angularjs to render my html and using bootstrap 3 to style it.  The tabs render correctly, but the images within each tab do not display in a grid, rather, they are outputted one by one in a single column. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">

    <!--Nav Tabs-->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="{{'#' + retailProducts[0].Category}}"
                              role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                               {{retailProducts[0].Category}}
                           </a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="pro in retailProductsMinusFirst">
            <a href="{{'#' + pro.Category}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                {{pro.Category}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!--Tab Panes-->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="{{retailProducts[0].Category}}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <a ng-repeat="pro in retailProducts[0].Products" href="#"
                       class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{pro.Product.PrimaryPhotoUrl + '?height=100'}}"
                             alt="Product Photo" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="pro in retailProductsMinusFirst" class="tab-pane" 
             id="{{pro.Category}}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <a ng-repeat="img in pro.Products" href="#" class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{img.Product.PrimaryPhotoUrl + '?height=100'}}" 
                             alt="Product Photo" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: repeat the `col-sm-2` instead of it's content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeating the anchors. You need to repeat the column divs. Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="pro in retailProducts[0].Products" class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{pro.Product.PrimaryPhotoUrl + '?height=100'}}"
        alt="Product Photo" />
    </a>
</div>
```